# -moz-column doesn't work correctly with rtl direction

Tags: css, firefox, gecko, right-to-left

I have a div container with fixed height , fixed width and overflow hidden
I need to display text in 4 columns

The problem is :
with direction 'rtl' , firefox display the latest 4 columns and hide the rest
but I want to display the first 4 columns and hide the rest which is done by switching the direction to 'ltr' but it's arabic content and it have to be done using 'rtl' direction

any help , please!!
and sorry if I couldn't discuss the issue clearly

```
<div class="article">Arabic Content here</div>

.article {
-moz-column-count: 4;
-moz-column-gap: 10px;
-moz-column-width: 40px;
height: 171px;
width: 500px;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: justify;
}
```

Comment: it's a very question (and I've given you +1 for it), but one should note that a CSS declaration with a vendor prefix is *by definition* incomplete and is likely to have missing features. it's perfectly possible that this simply isn't implemented fully yet for rtl content.

Answer (score 1):

Old question but:

This is a firefox bug - if you try using `-webkit-column-count: 4;` combined with `direction:rtl` and `overflow:hidden` you get your desired result in webkit browsers.

You will have to wait until a fix goes in (currently in FF 6.0.2 it's still bugged).